# Branch moving back and forth, is it necessary to provide new version each time? Git

Tags: git, web-applications, version-control, software-design

I have done multiple tasks in different **Git** branches, now few tasks are taking too much time for QA, so that branch is moving back and forth many times, so the question is whenever I deliver the same branch to QA again is it necessary to generate new build version each time?

Thanks

Comment: Do you merge all tasks into a main branch before tested by QA? It seems all the tasks are tested together.

Comment: And what do you changed after moving back? Whether to build new version is depend on what you changed.

Comment: I have the develop branch and created another branch ABC from develop, now whatever new changes happens in develop, I'm merging to ABC branch, but ABC have different changes which not merge yet with develop now QA wants me to give that branch on QA, the testing taking too much time, if QA tesing taking too much will not move farward that branch to prod, then need to move back, but when again I give to QA then again new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you can work on `ABC` branch, but after that, you should **merge changes from `ABC` branch into `develop` branch** (since we always need to treat one branch as main not both of them), so that the `develop` branch will contain all the changes both for itself and `ABC` branch.

And QA team only need to test your `develop` branch. If they move `develop` branch back, and you make changes on it, you should build with new version. Else, you have made no changes on it, you don’t need to build new version.

Comment: Hmm, you right, we always need to treat one branch, Thank you